# Consecutive Integer key to Integer value Hash vs Integer Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, integer, convention

This question is in regards to convention. Whether to use array or hash for consecutive integer keys to integer values?

For example, I am reading through a file. Each line contains other information as well as a time in the form of 19:45. I want to find which hours show up the most. Should I use an array or hash to tally them?

Comment: sorry fixed the typo

Comment: Very unclear to me what you're trying to do. A simplified version of the input compared to the output you're trying to achieve might help. Also, do either of your approaches currently work?

Comment: Sorry fixed more typos. I tried to type from memory instead of copy/paste because I don't have access to the file right now.

Comment: I also would request a  "simplified version of the input compared to the output you're trying to achieve" like @FrederickCheung asked. In general, if the job can be done will with an Array, I would do it that way rather than with a Hash.

Comment: @Skram Thanks, that is what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using an array because hash is not an integer index.